# Spring 3.0 webapp NoClassDefFoundError - classpath issue

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

My webapp fails to find *org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean* class despite having *org.springframework.web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar* in the WEB-INF/lib directory. If I add an older version of spring.jar(2.5.6) to the webapp, then the class is found. Any ideas why this may be occurring and how I can fix it without reverting to spring-2.5.6 or keeping both versions of spring in the same webapp?

I am deploying on Tomcat 6.0.28.

Here's the error:

- Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/remoting/httpinvoker/HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean

Here are the spring jars in the classpath (WEB-INF/lib):

- org.springframework.aop-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.asm-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.expression-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
- org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar

Possibly related questions:

- [Spring Framework 3.0.5 MVC Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716697/spring-framework-3-0-5-mvc-issue)
- [NoClassDefFoundError in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014465/noclassdeffounderror-in-spring)

Comment: Is the class present in these jars?

Comment: it is present in org.springframework.web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Could you post stack trace? `NoClassDefFoundError` isn't the same as `ClassNotFoundException`. It means the class definition used inside `HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean` cannot be found, not the class itself.

Comment: You may need `aopalliance-1.0.jar`

Comment: Please try to add commons-httpclient.jar as well

Comment: @gigadot .. adding aopalliance-1.0.jar fixed it. Please post that as the answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` isn't the same as `ClassNotFoundException`. It means the class definition used inside `HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean` cannot be found, not the class itself.

In other words, all the import classes of `HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean` and of its superclasses must be found in your classpath.

Since the `HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean` is a subclass of `org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory` and `ProxyFactory` depends on `aopalliance-1.0.jar`, you will need to include this in your classpath.